# Android Gradle Error: 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST' Conflict Causes Run Option to Disappear

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android app for my college project, but I'm encountering an error that's preventing me from building the app successfully. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

> (3 files found with path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'.
> Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
> https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
> for more information)

I tried to resolve the issue by adding a packagingOptions block in my Gradle build file like this:

```
(3 files found with path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'.
Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
for more information)
```

However, when I added this block, the "Run" option disappeared in Android Studio.

Here is my complete Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.primeiraapp'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.primeiraapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.27.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why the "Run" option disappeared after adding the packagingOptions block and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What gradle version is set up for your project?

Comment: android gradle version-7.3.1 gradle version -7.4